# How to convert a tuple list to a normal one in Python or remove parts of text from tuple?

Tags: python, psycopg2

```
sql = '''select datname from pg_database; '''

cursor.execute(sql)
dbs=[]
for dbase in cursor.fetchall():
    dbs.append(dbase)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
print(dbs)
clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(dbs[0])
db_choice = OptionMenu(row1,clicked,*dbs)
```

And

```
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database=clicked.get(),
        user="postgres",
        password="Testuser12")

    print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'""")
    db_tables = []
    for table in cursor.fetchall():
        print(table)
        db_tables.append(table)
```

Whenever I try to execute my code I get this error:

connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "('postgres',)" does not exist

I cannot remove (' ',) part because they are in a tuple. I also tried converting tuple to normal list but it doesn't seem to work and I get this error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

What should I do?

Comment: provide a [mre] and the entire traceback

Comment: note in passing that there are tuples, and there are lists (and there are other datatypes).  None is more 'normal' than the other, but tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Just access the first element of the tuple. If `dbase=('postgres',)`, then `x=dbase[0]` will be `'postgres'`.

`x,=dbase` would also work, but you should avoid this kind of unpacking notation if you're not familiar with it.